# Creating new objects for select dropdowns in Angular

Tags: html, angular

This is a simplified version of my problem, as my model is much bigger.

I'm generating a drop-down from a set of objects, and using the object.Name property of each to fill the select.

```
<md-select [(ngModel)]="selectedDetachment" placeholder="Select a detachment">
    <md-option *ngFor="let option of detachmentOptions" [value]="option">
        {{option.Name}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

the `detachmentOptions` object is a generated set of 3 objects, all of which extend `Detachment`,

```
private detachmentOptions: Detachment[];

this.detachmentOptions = [
    new DetachmentPatrol(),
    new DetachmentBattalion(),
    new DetachmentBrigade()
];
```

I want to add a detachment to my main army, based on the select, which uses the following function

```
addDetachment() {
    if(this.selectedDetachment) {
        this.army.Detachments.push(this.selectedDetachment.constructor());
        // this.makeDetachmentOptions();
    }
}
```

My problem is that this uses the orignal, as JS inherantly passes by reference. No matter how many copies of `DetachmentBattaliion` I add, they all contain the same contents, as they are each references to the original created in the constructor.

I need to be able to create a brand-new blank object of the type selected, and I'm completely blanking on how to do this.

`Object.prototype()` gets the prototype, so I can't get the type, and I can't find a way to use `typeof` to genearate a new copy of the object.

It does not need to copy the object wholesale, I just need a method of creating the original type, without tying them together by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash's `cloneDeep`. It creates a new object instance instead of referencing the same object.

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash';

...

export class ... {
  private detachmentOptions: Detachment[];

  ...


  addDetachment() {
    if(this.selectedDetachment) {
      const selectedDetachment = cloneDeep(this.selectedDetachment);
      this.army.Detachments.push(selectedDetachment.constructor());
      // this.makeDetachmentOptions();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked a tread, although my IDE isn't recognising the package; it is still funtioning fine

Comment: @KilleR I had this issue on VSCode a few times. Sometimes relaunching the IDE helps. You may also try changing the order of imports.

Answer (score 0):

you may try below,

```
 addDetachment() {
    if(this.selectedDetachment) {
      const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this.selectedDetachment);
      const instance = Object.create(prototype);
      this.army.Detachments.push(instance);
      console.log(instance);
      console.log(this.army);
    }
  }
```

Check this [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/cT6Z5rejMrdoffkeBTIz?p=preview)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, they are a subtype of Detachment, and getPrototypeOf just gives the higher prototype class.